# Is there a way to DeserializeObject without empty constructor?

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, xunit

I am currently in the progress of enabling non-nullable reference types for my .net core api.

The problem is that the integrationtest fails when trying to deserializeObject because it has no empty constructor. I can't have an empty constructor because that will make property: *possible null*.

The problem:

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ViewModel>(result);` calls the constructor which has a constructor with an object argument `ViewModel(Model model)`. In the test this is null.

I have made a simple sample:

**The api:**

```
public class Dog
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    }

    public class DogViewModel
    {

        public DogViewModel(Dog dog)
        {
            Name = dog.Name;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


    [HttpGet]
    [Route("dog")]
    public DogViewModel GetDog()
    {
        var dog = new Dog
        {
            Name = "Fido"
        };
        return new DogViewModel(dog);
    }
```

This works when I use a client to call the api, but it fails from the tests:

**Test**

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task GetDog()
    {

        var response = await Client.GetAsync("dog");

        var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        Assert.True(response.IsSuccessStatusCode, result);
        var responeseAsObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DogViewModel>(result); <----- this is where it breaks
        Assert.IsType<string>(responeseAsObject.Name);
        Assert.NotNull(responeseAsObject);
    }
```

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject calls the constructor of DogViewModel;  DogViewModel(Dog dog), but dog is null.

Comment: Can you post here the json format ?

Comment: I'am not sure what you mean. public DogViewModel(Dog dog), in this case, dog is null. Can i set a default value for that?

Comment: An empty constructor is just a constructor that takes 0 arguments. It can have a body but cannot have any parameters. If you pass a null object to a constructor, the constructor still has an argument, its just null.

Comment: @Mr.AF   Json i get in the test: {"name":"Fido"}

Comment: Why not just `public DogViewModel(string name) { Name = name; }`? You could even make the `Name` property read-only as JSON.Net also tries to populate constructor parameters with JSON keys that have the same (case-insensitive) name.

Comment: @ckuri because in **actual** case it takes in a big object, which does some converting on some of the properties

Comment: But the requirement is nonsensical. A DTO, used to deserialize a piece of external data into, **must** support `null`. `{}` is valid JSON, and can be deserialized into a `Dog` instance, but that `Dog` will have a `Name` property of `null`. That's just a fact of life when deserializing data. The only way to prevent this is to add validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is, as @CodeCaster points out, nonsensical- But i found a non-optimal solution.

In the test project i created this:

```
  public class TestDogViewModel : DogViewModel
    {

        public TestDogViewModel() : base(new Dog {Name = ""})
        {
        }

    }
```

When deserializing i used this:

```
var responeseAsObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestDogViewModel>(result);
```

Developers won't use this viewModel by mistake since the project doesn't have a reference to the test project,

So now if you want to have a DogViewModel you would need to have a dog. It kinda makes more sense in my real project :S.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that your question is nonsensical, as a "how to" it's very valid. But indeed perhaps in your actual project this makes sense.

Comment: Oh, I thought your point was valid. It was meant as a thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Populate the class with default values. With null able reference types, the default value would be null, so in your case just assign the default value that you expect.

```
public class ClassName
{
    public ClassName()
    {
        Name = string.Empty; //Default value
    }

    public ClassName(Dog dog)
    {
        Name = dog.Name;
    }

}
```

Or

```
public class ClassName
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public ClassName() {}

    public ClassName(Dog dog)
    {
        Name = dog.Name;
    }

}
```

The serializer will construct a new object. The object contains a string member, and you have disabled null-able reference types. Thus you need to specify what the value will be when the object is created.

If you don't want to use the default constructor (An empty constructor), you can tell the serialiser the constructor you would like to use:
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm

Comment: The problem with this is that some other developer can use the Empty constructor, but I want to force them to use the one with the object. Because this will lie, if we new Dog() it would imply that there is dog with name "", but it is actual. This how we would do it before, but we are trying somethign new :)

Comment: I've updated the answer with an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct behavior `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` uses constructor to just create an object. It won't pass any parameter to it and that's why you are getting an error.

What's happening is, `dog` is null and hence your assignment of `Name = dog.Name;` throws `NullreferenceException`.

You should ideally check `dog` for null before using it in your constructor.

```
    public DogViewModel(Dog dog)
    {
        Name = dog?.Name;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From docs.microsoft:
The Newtonsoft.Json [JsonConstructor] attribute lets you specify which constructor to call when deserializing to a POCO. System.Text.Json supports only parameterless constructors. As a workaround, you can call whichever constructor you need in a custom converter.
--> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to#deserialize-to-immutable-classes-and-structs

Maybe this could be a solution